# Swift Custom URL is not opening the app from extension

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme, ios8-share-extension

I have a `Share-Extension` from which I would like to redirect the user to the main app. This is what I tried:

```
let signInAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Anmelden", style: .default) { (alert) in
        let myAppUrl = NSURL(string: "open://")!
        self.extensionContext?.open(myAppUrl as URL, completionHandler: { (success) in
            if (!success) {
                // let the user know it failed
                print("fail!")
            }
        })
}
```

And my `info-plist` :

[image]

Right now it is printing the "fail!". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you trying to share your app address from the app store or are you trying to open a url?

Comment: @Lance Samaria I am trying to open the app from the extension

Comment: do you have your app address from the app store?

Comment: @LanceSamaria its not on the app store yet

Comment: I'm lost. Are you trying to open your app from within the app? Are you trying to open another app from within your app? Are you trying to open a url? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do

Comment: @LanceSamaria sorry if I was unclear. I have an `ShareExtension` which I use in Safari. And from Safari I would like to open my app

Comment: How can you open your app if it isn't in the app store yet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217553/discussion-between-chris-and-lance-samaria).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your project settings in xcode.
Did you set a custom url scheme in the "URL-Types" setting in your apps target?

[Xcode - Target - General Settings - URL Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNf7E.png)

Comment: yes I did. But I think its not really possible to access the main app from share extension